# Trying to find absolute value of expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to find the absolute value of the following complex number

```
    1/3 (1 + \[Beta]₁ + \[Beta]₂) + ((1 + 
      I Sqrt[3]) (-(-1 - \[Beta]₁ - \[Beta]₂)^2 + 
      3 (\[Beta]₁ \[Eta] + \[Beta]₂ \[Eta] + \[Beta]₂ \[Lambda]₁ - \
\[Beta]₁ \[Beta]₂ \[Lambda]₁)))/(3 2^(
    2/3) (2 + 6 \[Beta]₁ + 6 \[Beta]₁^2 + 2 \[Beta]₁^3 + 6 \[Beta]₂ + 
      12 \[Beta]₁ \[Beta]₂ + 6 \[Beta]₁^2 \[Beta]₂ + 6 \[Beta]₂^2 + 
      9 \[Beta]₂^2 \[Lambda]₁ + 9 \[Beta]₁ \[Beta]₂^2 \[Lambda]₁ +
      27 \[Eta] \[Lambda]₁ - 
      27 \[Beta]₁ \[Eta] \[Lambda]₁ + \[Sqrt]((2 + 6 \[Beta]₁ + 
           6 \[Beta]₁^2 + 2 \[Beta]₁^3 - 
           27 \[Beta]₁ \[Eta] \[Lambda]₁)^2 + 
         4 (-(-1 - \[Beta]₁ - \[Beta]₂)^2)^3))^(1/3))
```

But the Abs function simply returns Abs of the whole thing. If I ComplexExpand the whole thing I do get an absolute value but in a form I don't like, with Args, etc. Are there other ways to take the absolute value? Why does the standard one not work?

Comment: `ComplexExpand` assumes all variables are Real. Are you assuming that and not telling MMA this? Otherwise MMA assumes all variables are Complex. What are you expecting as a result when the only thing we can say about `Abs[1+x]` is that it is just `Abs[1+x]`?